# Importing Alamofire 3.3.1 into XCode 7.2, Swift 2.1.1

Tags: alamofire

This is my first post on SO so here goes...
I'm trying to import Alamofire 3.3.1 into Xcode 7.2, Swift 2.1.1.
I've tried pulling in the project as described here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/3.3.0/ and have also tried to the cocoa pods method as well.  Both of these result in 161 compile errors in the Alamofire portion of the project.

I've also tried other SO postings with offer similar steps, but they all boil down to adding the the Almofire Xcode project file into one's project and adding the embedded binary.

For example,

```
.../Alamofire/Source/Request.swift:487:17: error: expected expression in list of expressions
            protocol: URL.scheme,
            ^
.../Alamofire/Source/Request.swift:486:51: error: expected ',' separator
            port: URL.port?.integerValue ?? 0,
                                              ^
                                              ,
.../Alamofire/Source/Request.swift:487:17: error: expected ')' in expression list
            protocol: URL.scheme,
```

I've made sure that the target is correct (both set to 8.1).  The application I'm working with is for iOS.

I have searched the Alamofire SO posts and haven't seen anything recently so I'm assuming there's some simple step I've missed.

The sample tutorial I'm following along with successfully builds with an older version of Alamofire - 2.0 - should I assume that the new version of Alamofire doesn't work with Swift 2.1.1?

Thanks so much.

Update: I figured this out - reading the code more closely, the latest version of Alamofire uses #selector which was introduced with Swift 2.2 (which is used in Xcode 7.3, El Capitain).   SO, there you have it. For example, the following code Manager.swift uses #selector

```
public override func respondsToSelector(selector: Selector) -> Bool {
#if !os(OSX)
    if selector == #selector(NSURLSessionDelegate.URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession(_:)) {
        return sessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession != nil
    }
#endif

switch selector {
case #selector(NSURLSessionDelegate.URLSession(_:didBecomeInvalidWithError:)):
return sessionDidBecomeInvalidWithError != nil
case #selector(NSURLSessionDelegate.URLSession(_:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:)):
return (sessionDidReceiveChallenge != nil  || sessionDidReceiveChallengeWithCompletion != nil)
case #selector(NSURLSessionTaskDelegate.URLSession(_:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)):
return (taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection != nil || taskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionWithCompletion != nil)
case #selector(NSURLSessionDataDelegate.URLSession(_:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler:)):
return (dataTaskDidReceiveResponse != nil || dataTaskDidReceiveResponseWithCompletion != nil)
default:
    return self.dynamicType.instancesRespondToSelector(selector)
}
```

This definitely won't compile with Swift 2.1